# Irreducibility of quadratic polynomial in Z[x]

Tags: quadratics, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to ask, how to test irreducibility of quadratic polynomial.
I found, that when square root of discriminant is integer, $\sqrt{D}\in Z, D=b^2-4ac$, the polynomial can
reduced. The document is here
http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/galois/CHAP03%20Prime%20Polynomials.pdf
In terms of this ducument question is, what is the proof of Primeness test 2.
I understand that you can factorize quadratic polynomial, if you have integer roots,
but what if $\sqrt{D}\in Z$ and  $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{D}}{2a}\in Q$?

Comment: A quadratic (or even cubic) polynomial over *any* field is reducible iff it has at least one root in that field.

Comment: Note that the test assumes that the coefficient ring is a *field*.

Comment: ok, so I know, that $a,b,c\in Z$ even I know $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\in Z$. Does it somehow imply, that roots of polynomial are in Z?

Comment: Ok, sorry, now I see, Z is not a field right? Hm so this test of discriminant is not applicable for Z.

Comment: @DonAntonio and what about for example $(3x+5)(4x+7)=12x^2+41x+35$.It has rational roots, but can be reduced in integers. Well I want irreducibility in integers, so since it is not a field, it doesnt apply. But is there some easy way to recognize irreducibility in integers?

Answer (score 4):

The contrapositive of [Gauss's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29) says that if a integer polynomial is reducible over the rationals, then it is reducible over the integers.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental reason for the reducibility is given in the answer by Hurkyl. However, one can reason explicitly in this case as follows. Assume $D=b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square, so $d=\sqrt D$ is integer. Now one has $(b+d)(b-d)=b^2-D=4ac$, and the numbers $b+d$ and $b-d$ both have the same parity, which clearly cannot be odd. Then $\frac{b+d}2\times\frac{b-d}2=ac$ is an equality in $\def\Z{\mathbf Z}\Z$. But the unique factorization property of $\Z$, all prime factors of $a$ must be present in one of the factors on the left, so one can decompose $a=st$ in $\Z$ such that $\frac{b+d}{2s},\frac{b-d}{2t}\in\Z$, and then $\frac{b+d}{2s}\times\frac{b+d}{2t}=c$. Now one can decompose in $\Z[X]$:
$$
  aX^2+bX+c = \Bigl(tX+\frac{b+d}{2s}\Bigr)\Bigl(sX+\frac{b-d}{2t}\Bigr).
$$